# opensource add-on / module to assign tags to otrs tickets

Tags: otrs

OTRS comes with a [TagCloud](https://www.otrs.com/feature-add-on/tagcloud/) add-on / module, unfortunately only available to [subscribers](https://www.otrs.com/homepage/solutions/service-contracts/). I wasn't able to find ANY opensource alternative or even any forum posting on how to roll my own solution. I assume that `dynamic fields` could be a way to go but I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

I'd like to implement the following functionality:

- tag incoming tickets (1st level, 2nd level, hardware, software, network, etc)
- detect trends of incoming problems by looking at tags

Comment: I think this isn't trivial, because you'll need deep knowledge of OTRS and Perl.

Answer (score 0):

The OTRS add-on may not do what you think it does. I think it does not allow you to freely add tags to tickets, like you'd tag a question here in SE. It's just a different visualization of ticket data, including dynamic fields.